# Is it more pythonic to separate Exception catches or do them within one try-block? Python

Tags: python, exception

I hope this is not too opinion based, but I've understood that the Python community has some strong guidelines for how to use exception handling, though I couldn't find any commentary fitting to my situation.

I'm in the process of writing the main API function of a web-based script. The incoming data is first preprocessed/sanitized, then pushed through the complicated processing, and the result is finally postprocessed/formatted before being sent back to the requester. Each of the three parts can fail due to various reasons, so I need to wrap them into try-except blocks.

My question is: *Is it more pythonic to wrap the whole process in one try-except -block an capture various types of exceptions, or to create individual blocks?* I.e., of the following two styles, should I prefer one of them?

**Version 1**

```
def main(input_data):
    
    try:
        parsed_data = parse_incoming_data(input_data)
    except LookupError as e:   
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Misformatted data, key not found: {e}", status_code=400)

    try:
        processed_data = big_process(parsed_data)
    except CustomProcessingException as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Main service failed due to {e}.", status_code=500)

    try:
        output = postprocess_result(processed_data)
    except CustomPostprocessingException as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Postprocessing error {e}.", status_code=555)

    return func.HttpResponse(output, status_code=200)
```

**Version 2**

```
def main(input_data):
    
    try:
        parsed_data = parse_incoming_data(input_data)
        processed_data = big_process(parsed_data)
        output = postprocess_result(processed_data)
    except LookupError as e:   
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Misformatted data, key not found: {e}", status_code=400)
    except CustomProcessingException as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Main service failed due to {e}.", status_code=500)
    except CustomPostprocessingException as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Postprocessing error {e}.", status_code=555)

    return func.HttpResponse(output, status_code=200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the specifics of the code and the errors being thrown.

With the first way, say `processed_data = big_process(parsed_data)` fails.  `output = postprocess_result(processed_data)` will still run since they're separate checks. Also, all three failures have the potential to be handled in three different ways.

With the second way, say the first line fails. The third line will not run since execution is transferred to the `except` block. Also, all three failures will be handled the same way (unless you manually use flags or some other mechanism to differentiate).

So the answer is, neither is really more Pythonic. The pieces of code are not equivalent, so you should use whichever is more appropriate for your particular case.